# Log rotation is stopped after rotation of some files(creating new files but stopped deleting old files)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

when counter reaches to 900's log file's stopped deleting old files why?

logging:

```
level:
    root: INFO
pattern:
    file: "%d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} ${HOSTNAME} ${spring.application.name} ${server.port} %-6level-%logger{36}.%M-%msg%n"
    rolling-file-name: ${logging.file.path}/${spring.application.name}-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log   
file:
    name: ${logging.file.path}/${spring.application.name}.log
    path: logs
    max-size: 10kB
    total-size-cap: 100KB
    max-history: 1
```

Comment: I configured more logger, but there was never such a need. I don't even see the point. Basically, logos are generated in large quantities, so it's worth cutting them either by size or by hour/day. With 1,000 entries per minute, what's the point of storing more than 1.4 million files in one day?

Comment: what is the configuration of more logger